# Magento 1.7.0.1 UPS XML rates incorrect when Free Method of Ground is enabled

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods, debugging, free-shipping, ups

I don't often get completely stumped, but has anyone see this before. When rates were being calculated using Magento 1 UPS method set to XML rates were being returned but completely off.  The first screenshot you can see that Ground is coming back the most expensive.

[image: Ground Rate should be ~$250]

I then continued to work through the site, I investigated the UPS XML logs in real time, and the rates being returned weren't even in the ballpark of what I was seeing on the Front-end.  So I did the whole, it's working in QA but not in production, what's different.  Upon investigation, I found UPS's Free shipping Method enabled as "Ground". I didn't think this would cause the issue, but I disabled it and tried again.  Low and behold rates came back as expected.  Screen Shot Below:

[image: It works, but I don't know why. :(]

Has anyone seen anything like this before, or had an issue with the UPS free shipping module? I may just start stepping through code in the meantime to see what happens.  Hope someone can help!

Robert